# Collaborative filtering through matrix factorization with logistic loss function

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

Consider collaborative filtering problem. We have matrix $M$ of size #users * #items. $M_{i,j} = 1$ if user i likes item j, $M_{i,j} = 0$ if user i dislikes item j and $M_{i,j}=?$ if there is no data about (i,j) pair. We want to predict $M_{i,j}$ for future user, item pairs.

Standard collaborative filtering approach is to represent M as product of 2 matrices $U \times V$ such that $||M - U \times V||_2$ is minimal (e.g. minimizing mean square error for known elements of $M$).

To me logistic loss function seems more suitable, why are all algorithms using MSE?

Comment: In this case it makes sense but most of the time M_i,j can be a rating and in that case the MSE is more useful. I'd say that the MSE is more general.

Answer (score 12):

We use logistic loss for implicit matrix factorization at Spotify in the context of music recommendations (using play counts). We've just published a paper on our method in an upcoming NIPS 2014 workshop. The paper is titled Logistic Matrix Factorization for Implicit Feedback Data and can be found here http://stanford.edu/~rezab/nips2014workshop/submits/logmat.pdf

Code for the paper can be found on my Github https://github.com/MrChrisJohnson/logistic-mf

Comment: I had a look to the paper you published. It is very interesting since matrix factorization with logistic regression has not been not actively studied.
Anyway, I am a bit confused with your Loss function (2) L(R | X, Y, β) = Prod( p(lui | xu, yi, βu, βi)^α.r_ui * (1 − p(lui | xu, yi
, βu, βi)) Regarding (3), I think that there is a typo mistaske L(R | X, Y, β) = Prod( p(lui | xu, yi, βu, βi)^α.r_ui * (1 − p(lui | xu, yi
, βu, βi))^ **(1 + α.r_ui**) But, actually, I am still a bit confused. Indeed, I would have expected a Bernouilli-like law such as

Comment: L(R | X, Y, β) = Prod( p(lui | xu, yi, βu, βi)^α.r_ui * (1 − p(lui | xu, yi
, βu, βi))^ **(1 - α.r_ui)** A had a look to your code, and you do use **1+α.r_ui** l64 : A = (self.counts + self.ones) * A https://github.com/MrChrisJohnson/logistic-mf/blob/master/logistic_mf.py Therefore, am i missing something? Kind regards

Comment: Maybe I'm quite late on the subject.. someone had the chance to try this algo outside the context of music recommendation and instead the classical context of product recommendation? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the papers you'll find on the subject will deal with matrices where the ratings are on a scale [0,5]. In the context of the Netflix Prize for example, matrices have discrete ratings from 1 to 5 (+ the missing values). That's why the squared error is the most spread cost function. Some other error measures such as the Kullback-Leibler divergence can be seen.

Another problem that can occur with standard matrix factorization is that some of the elements of the matrices **U** and **V** may be **negative** (particularly during the first steps). That's a reason why you wouldn't use the log-loss here as your cost function.

However, if you're talking about **Non-negative Matrix Factorization** you should be able to use the log-loss as your cost function. You are in a  similar case than Logistic Regression where log-loss is used as the cost function: your observed values are 0's and 1's and you predict a number (probability) between 0 and 1.